# Is there a better way to improve my add record method?

Tags: c#, linq, ibm-midrange

I am working with data on our IBM i server. The driver I am using to connect from .NET cannot do LINQ or Entity Framework. I know there is another driver, but that is costly and I have yet to figure out if that will actually work based on everything I have seen online.

So to "work around" this limitation, I pull the data from the server into a data table then immediately put that data into a more LINQ friendly model.

Most of the tables I have worked with thus far don't have too many columns where it gets annoying to copy-paste parameters to make it work. Now I have a file with a TON of columns.

```
SELECT DDATE, DPERNO, DPIN, DCODE, DCODE2, DESTCS, DBLDBP, DPERMP, DADFEE, DPRFEE, 
    DSURCR, DTTFEE, DSTNU, DSTEX, DSTNA, DSTSU, DDIR, DAPTS, DBORI, DSUBDV, DDIREC, 
    DSITED, DLEGAL, DAPPCD, DOWNER, DOWNAD, DONAD2, DOWNCT, DOWNST, DOWNZP, DOWPH1, 
    DOWCM1, DOWPH2, DOWCM2, DCMPNY, DCONTR, DCONAD, DCNAD2, DCONCT, DCONST, DCONZP, 
    DCNPH1, DCNCM1, DCNPH2, DCNCM2, DCNCPH, DCTRNO, DSPRCD, DTYCON, DTYCN2, DDEMO, 
    DZONE, DCOMDT, DSTRWD, DSTRDP, DSTYNO, DPROPT, DSETFR, DSETRR, DSETLF, DSETRT, 
    DATTGR, DUNAGR, DTYOCC, DSQFOT, DLOTCO, DPLMNM, DCONCD, DDIVIS, DARCHT, DENGIR, 
    DINSPC, DVARCE, DDTPD, DDTCOM, DUNITS, DVOID, DINSFL, DBLDCD, DCAUKY, DCAPIN  
  FROM MYTABLE
```

I am writing my method to do an insert and figure there has to be a better way.

```
    public bool AddBuildingPermit(BuildingPermit bp)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("INSERT INTO QMFILES.PBMASTP ");
        sb.Append("VALUES(@DDATE, @DPERNO, @DPIN, @DCODE, @DCODE2, @DESTCS, @DBLDBP, @DPERMP, @DADFEE, @DPRFEE, @DSURCR, @DTTFEE, @DSTNU, ");
        sb.Append("@DSTEX, @DSTNA, @DSTSU, @DDIR, @DAPTS, @DBORI, @DSUBDV, @DDIREC, @DSITED, @DLEGAL, @DAPPCD, @DOWNER, @DOWNAD, ");
        sb.Append("@DONAD2, @DOWNCT, @DOWNST, @DOWNZP, @DOWPH1, @DOWCM1, @DOWPH2, @DOWCM2, @DCMPNY, @DCONTR, @DCONAD, @DCNAD2, @DCONCT, ");
        sb.Append("@DCONST, @DCONZP, @DCNPH1, @DCNCM1, @DCNPH2, @DCNCM2, @DCNCPH, @DCTRNO, @DSPRCD, @DTYCON, @DTYCN2, @DDEMO, @DZONE, ");
        sb.Append("@DCOMDT, @DSTRWD, @DSTRDP, @DSTYNO, @DPROPT, @DSETFR, @DSETRR, @DSETLF, @DSETRT, @DATTGR, @DUNAGR, @DTYOCC, @DSQFOT, ");
        sb.Append("@DLOTCO, @DPLMNM, @DCONCD, @DDIVIS, @DARCHT, @DENGIR, @DINSPC, @DVARCE, @DDTPD, @DDTCOM, @DUNITS, @DVOID, @DINSFL, ");
        sb.Append("@DBLDCD, @DCAUKY, @DCAPIN)");

        using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(_connString))
        {
            using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sb.ToString(), conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DDATE", iDB2DbType.iDB2Decimal).Value = IbmIDateTime.ConvertToNumericDate(bp.DateApplied);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DPERNO", iDB2DbType.iDB2Decimal).Value = GetNextBuildingPermitNumber();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DPIN", iDB2DbType.iDB2Char).Value = bp.CommonAddressPin;
                /// add all of the fields here
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Besides copy-paste/modify for each field. Is there a way I can make this easier. Maybe a loop or something?

Comment: this should be posted at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I was wondering about that. I figure it's a grey area. Move if it should be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Use DataAnnotations attributes [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) and [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute) then using reflection build your queries with a single method.

```
[Table("QMFILES.PBMASTP")]
public class QMFILESPBMASTP
{
    [Column("DDATE")]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}

public bool AddRecord<T>(T model)
{
  var tlbInfo = System.Attribute
                      .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), 
                                          typeof(CustomTableAttribute)) 
                      as CustomTableAttribute;

  var cols = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                      .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute),
                                                        true)
                                   .Count() == 1)
                      .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute),
                                                         true)
                                    .First() as ColumnAttribute);
  var colNames = cols.Select(c => c.Name);


  if (tblInfo != null && cols.Count() > 0)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("INSERT INTO ");
    sb.Append(tlbInfo.Name);
    sb.Append("VALUES(@");
    sb.Append(string.Join(", @", colNames.ToArray()));

    // etc
  }
}
```

Comment: This worries me as I look at it more. It looks to me like this is ripe for SQL injection. I am just going to copy-paste my code to make it work.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, all the values are parameterized.  I simply didn't provide the code to add the Parameter values.

Comment: Oh... I am not looking to replace the query, I am looking to replace the parameters.